# How to avoid UIToolbar's tintColor to change UIButtonItem button color?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In iOS7,I Created a `UIBarButtonItem` and init with a image which color is green.But the final appearance of that  `UIBarButtonItem`'s image is a image with the same shape but different color.The color was changed to blue.

The code is below:

```
_recordVoiceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"voiceIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

    _textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 4, 220, BOTTOM_BAR_HEIGHT - 2*4)];
    _textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;

    _rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"modeIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

    _bottomBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height - BOTTOM_BAR_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, BOTTOM_BAR_HEIGHT)];

    _bottomBar.items = @[_recordVoiceItem,[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_textView],_rightItem];

    [self.view addSubview:_bottomBar];
```

And I have tried to create a `UIToolBar` and add some items to it through Interface Builder.The appearance is fine. The color of the `UIBarButtonItem`'s image was the origin image's color.

I doubt that I need to add some code to set some properties of the `UIToolBar` or `UIBarButtonItem` if I want to it through writing code. Could you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although it should not be required, my colored UIBarButtonItem since iOS7 are done with:

For **Objective C**:

```
UIImage* itemImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"]; // Colored Image
itemImage         = [itemImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
_itemButton       = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:itemImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(itemSelected:event:)];
```

**UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal** is the key here.

For **Swift 3**:

```
    // Use the colored image menu.png as a UIBarButtonItem
    if var itemImage   = UIImage(named: "menu") {
        itemImage      = itemImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let itemButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: itemImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.itemSelected(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = itemButton
    }
```

Again, .**withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)** is the key here.

Comment: This `tintColor` and new API in `UIImage` is the greatest API design fail I've ever seen. In documentation of `tintColor` apple should add link to this `UIImage` method.

Comment: I had been looking a lot to override tint color. Works well Thanks Francois :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following code:

```
_bottomBar.transculantColor = No;
[_bottomBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: That code does not take effect.How to avoid UIToolbar tintColor to change UIButtonItem button color?